# How to pass an id in URL to controller? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to deal with some data rows with same `key_id`. I want them to get select by using an id in URL, so I will have `/field_data/index/12` and 12 here means the `key_id`.

I can manually do it in the controller by hardcoding the `key_id`

```
def index 
    @key_id = 12
    @field_data = FieldDatum.select('field_content').where("key_id = ?", @key_id)
end
```

and my URL is very general: `/field_data`

So how to make it be able to get the id in URL?

Comment: According to your path `/field_data/index/12` the id `12` should be in `params` have you seen it?

Answer (score 4):

routes

```
get "/field_data/index/:key_id", to: "field_datas#index"
```

controller

```
def index 
  @field_data = FieldDatum.select('field_content').where(key_id: params[:key_id])
end
```

Comment: I assume `/field_data/:key_id` not `/field_data/index/:key_id`, OP edit the question since.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, thank you for the comment.

this works perfectly, only need to change a little bit, in routes

`to: "field_data#index"`  I realized that **data** is plural of **datum** when I do the project,

Comment: @Зелёный if that were the case I would just use a normal resources route and use the show action personally.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Show.html.erb

```
<% user_all.each do |user| %>
   <%= link_to user_id_pass_path(user.id), method: :get do %>
    <span class="btn btn-warning">Pass Id</span>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
 get '/user_id_pass/:id' => 'users#user_id_pass', as: 'user_id_pass'
```

users_controller.rb

```
 def user_id_pass
   @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
 end
```